# Check if string is palindrome in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to check if a string is palindrome or not using objective c. I'm new to programming without any experience in other programming languages so bear with me please. I get stuck at my if condition I want it to say that if the first position in the string is equal to the last one the string is a palindrome.

What im a doing wrong?

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSString *p = @"121" ;   
    BOOL palindrome = TRUE;
    for (int i = 0 ; i<p.length/2+1 ; i++)
    {
         if (p[i] != p [p.Length - i - 1])
                    palindrome = false;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing your `{}` aren't balanced. (If you're getting an error message when compiling your code, you should always mention what it is--as written, it appeared you were asking about your program logic.)

Comment: Another trick would be to reverse the string (well documented) and test `isEqualToString`

Comment: @RobvanderVeer I'm not aware that reversing a string is well documented. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Rosetta Code: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reverse_a_string#Objective-C

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the unbalanced braces, accessing a character from NSString is more complicated than using array notation. You need to use the method `characterAtIndex:` You can optimise your code, by breaking out of the loop if a palindrome is impossible and taking the length call outside of the for loop.

```
NSString *p = @"121";

NSInteger length = p.length;
NSInteger halfLength = (length / 2);

BOOL isPalindrome = YES;

for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++) {
     if ([p characterAtIndex:i] != [p characterAtIndex:length - i - 1]) {
        isPalindrome = NO;
        break;
     }
}
```

It may be desirable to check case insensitively. To do this, make the string be all lowercase before looping, using the `lowercaseString` method.

As pointed out by Nikolai in the comments, this would only work for strings containing 'normal' unicode characters, which is often not true — such as when using UTF8 for foreign languages. If this is a possibility, use the following code instead, which checks composed character sequences rather than individual characters.

```
NSString *p = @"121";
NSInteger length = p.length;

NSInteger halfLength = length / 2;

__block BOOL isPalindrome = YES;

[p enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, halfLength) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
     NSRange otherRange = [p rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:length - enclosingRange.location - 1];

     if (![substring isEqualToString:[p substringWithRange:otherRange]]) {
         isPalindrome = NO;
         *stop = YES;
     }
}];
```

Comment: This only works if you make sure that the NSString does not contain surrogate pairs or combining characters. Iterating unicode characters is not trivial.

Comment: Updated with alternative snippet that enumerates composed character sequences rather than just unicode characters.

Comment: What is the __block for?

Comment: @BenjaminMayo This is still broken: You are creating character ranges at illegal boundaries. Best is to completely avoid calculating character positions. You can do that by using `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` to create a concatenated reverse string from the elements and compare that to the original string.

Comment: @Rob van der Veer the __block is to allow the block to change the variable value inside it.

Comment: @Ruhe Why is this creating illegal character ranges? If you have a mirrored string, the opposite boundary index must match up.

Comment: Many reasons: `substringWithRange:` would create broken string objects when applied in the middle of a surrogate pair. Also, there are often several ways to encode a character in unicode (de- vs. precomposed). Those encoding have different lengths.

Comment: The `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:` call prevents broken substrings.

Comment: Consider a string like "à" which consists of the unicode code points `LATIN SMALL LETTER A` and `COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT`. That's a string `length` of two. Your code would cut that into half (which already is wrong). In the loop you are using the `enclosingRange` (which also is slightly incorrect as you don't want to include separator characters). The main problem here is that you are expecting that you can calculate the range of the matching character by subtracting the current position from the end. That's not true if not all characters have identical lengths (as with the à example).

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use an `NSString` as an `NSArray` (or probably, like a C string), which won't work. Instead, you need to use the `NSString` method `characterAtIndex:` to get the character to test.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str: NSString = "123321"
var length = str.length
var isPalindrome = true

for index in 0...length/2{
    if(str.characterAtIndex(index) != str.characterAtIndex(length-1 - index)){
        print("\(index )not palindrome")
        isPalindrome = false
        break
    }
}

print("is palindrome: \(isPalindrome)")
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems there's no answer yet that handles composed character sequences correctly I'm adding my two cents:

```
NSString *testString = @"\u00E0 a\u0300"; // "à à"

NSMutableArray *logicalCharacters = [NSMutableArray array];
[testString enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange){0, [testString length]}
                               options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                            usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop)
{
    [logicalCharacters addObject:substring];
}];

NSUInteger count = [logicalCharacters count];
BOOL isPalindrome = YES;
for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx < count / 2; ++idx) {
    NSString *a = logicalCharacters[idx];
    NSString *b = logicalCharacters[count - idx - 1];
    if ([a localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:b] != NSOrderedSame) {
        isPalindrome = NO;
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"isPalindrome: %d", isPalindrome);
```

This splits the string into an array of logical characters (elements of a string that a normal user would call a "character").

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, i just have one more question: How do i print true or false value as any word i want?NSLog just prints them out as 1 or 0.

Comment: @user2384735 You should post this as another question.

Comment: I did not want to waste any space, but ok il open another question.

Answer (score 1):

**Recursive**

```
- (BOOL)isPaliRec:(NSString*)str :(int)start :(int)end{
    if(start >= end)
       return YES;
    else if([str characterAtIndex:start] != [str characterAtIndex:end])
       return NO;
    else
       return [self isPaliRec:str :++start :--end];
}
```

**Non Recursive**

```
- (BOOL)isPali:(NSString*)str{
   for (int i=0; i<str.length/2; i++)
      if([str characterAtIndex:i] != [str characterAtIndex:(str.length-i-1)])
         return NO;

   return YES;
}
```

**you can call:**

```
NSString *str = @"arara";
[self isPaliRec:str :0 :(int)str.length-1];
[self isPali:str];
```

**Swift 3:**

```
// Recursive
func isPaliRec(str: String, start: Int = 0, end: Int = str.characters.count-1) -> Bool {
    if start >= end {
        return true
    } else if str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: start)] != str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: end)] {
        return false
    } else {
        return isPaliRec(str: str, start: start+1, end: end-1)
    }
}

// Non Recursive
func isPali(str: String) -> Bool {
    for i in 0..<str.characters.count/2 {
        let endIndex = str.characters.count-i-1
        if str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)] != str[str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: endIndex)] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

// Using
let str = "arara"
isPaliRec(str: str)
isPali(str: str)
```

Also, you can use swift 3 methods like a `string extension`... It's more elegant. [extension sample](https://github.com/salesawagner/WASKit/blob/master/Sources/Extensions/String/String%2BWASPalindrome.swift)

Answer (score 1):

```
@import Foundation;

BOOL isPalindrome(NSString * str)
{
    if (!str || str.length == 0) return NO;
    if (str.length == 1) return YES;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < str.length / 2; ++i)
        if ([str characterAtIndex:i] != [str characterAtIndex:str.length - i - 1]) return NO;
    return YES;
}

int main() {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"%s", isPalindrome(@"applelppa") ? "YES" : "NO");
    } return 0;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *str=self.txtFld.text;
 int count=str.length-1;

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        char firstChar=[str characterAtIndex:i];
        char lastChar=[str characterAtIndex:count-i];
        NSLog(@"first=%c and last=%c",firstChar,lastChar);
        if (firstChar !=lastChar) {
            break;
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Pailndrome");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We can also do this using NSRange like this...
enter code  NSString *fullname=@"123321";
NSRange rangeforFirst=NSMakeRange(0, 1);
NSRange rangeforlast=NSMakeRange(fullname.length-1, 1);
BOOL ispalindrome;
for (int i=0; i<fullname.length; i++) {
    if (![[fullname substringWithRange:rangeforFirst] isEqualToString:[fullname substringWithRange:rangeforlast]]) {
        NSLog(@"not match");
        ispalindrome=NO;
        return;
    }
    i++;
    rangeforFirst=NSMakeRange(i, 1);
    rangeforlast=NSMakeRange(fullname.length-i-1, 1);
}
NSLog(@"no is %@",(ispalindrome) ? @"matched" :@"not matched");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str1 = @"racecar";
    NSMutableString *str2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSInteger strLength = [str1 length]-1;
    for (NSInteger i=strLength; i>=0; i--)
    {
       [str2 appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",[str1 characterAtIndex:i]]];

    }
 if ([str1 isEqual:str2])
        {
            NSLog(@"str %@ is palindrome",str1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)checkPalindromeNumber:(int)number{
    int originalNumber,reversedNumber = 0,remainder;
    originalNumber=number;
    while (number!=0) {
        remainder=number%10;
        reversedNumber=(reversedNumber*10)+remainder;
        number=number/10;
    }

    if (reversedNumber==originalNumber) {
        NSLog(@"%d is Palindrome Number",originalNumber);

        return YES;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%d is Not Palindrome Number",originalNumber);
        return NO;

    }
}
```